# Dropping rows in dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe train has 2704 rows with distinct customer id's under the column name "index".
Similarly another dataframe test has 8157 rows with distinct customer id's under the column name "index". I only want to keep the customer id's in test dataframe which are present in train dataset. How should i remove the rows in the test dataset based on the customer id values in the train dataset?

[image: test dataset]

[image: train dataset]

Comment: `test.loc[train_X.index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negation of `isin` to filter out `id`'s that are in `train_X`

```
test = test[~test['index'].isin(train_X['index'])]
```

To eliminate values in train, we just swap `test` and `train`. That is, do this instead of the above:

```
train_X = train_X[~train_X['index'].isin(test['index'])]
```

Comment: I understood the question differently.  I thought OP wanted the intersect of `test` with the `train_X` frame.

Comment: @r.ook yeah, I thought that too. But then it makes more sense to me having a `test` set that is independent from `train` set.

Comment: it is eliminating those values which are in the train dataset. how can we reverse it?

Comment: @SanniaNasir in that case, just `test = test.loc[train_X.index]` should suffice.

Comment: please do not confuse the dataframes on the basis of names. these are not train and test sets which are used for machine learning. assume it to be dataframe a and b. I understand that train and test sets are independent of eachother,

Comment: Simply put, if you want to keep use the vanila `isin()` without `~`, if you want to remove, use `~`.

Answer (score 0):

@Sannia,
         You can achieve that by using pd.merge or by filtering on the dataframe as shown below.

```py
   import pandas as pd

   # Approach - 1 
   df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2[["index"]], on="index")  # assuming df1 and df2 are your data frames 

   # Approach - 2
   index_vals = df2["index"].tolist()    
   df1_new = df1[df1["index"].isin(index_vals)]
```